# Mail.app doesn't have access to accounts after codesign

Tags: macos, code-signing, codesign

My steps were as follows:

1. Mail.app was working perfectly and only account there was with iCloud
2. I wanted to run mail.app that will be not displayed in Dock or Alt+Tab menu.
3. inside Mail.app/Contens/info.plist file I added special key 
   `<key>LSUIElement</key>
   <true/>`
4. Mail.app was crashing on start so I read it needs to be codesigned after that change.
5. I ran: `sudo codesign -f -s - Mail.app`
6. Mail.app is starting on the start it asked me to access to "Contacts". But it can't connect to imap server, further more I **can't make any changes or remove icloud account** in accounts tab in settings.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Adding LSUIElement also hides the menu bar. Therefore, this is not an option for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a programming question of general interest. At least, it should be moved to the "Ask Different" site.